# How to slide element using jQuery with append method?

Tags: jquery, append, sliding

I am trying to slide lists and want to loop it when the last child's animation is over the first will be added to the last which I am trying to use .append() method but its not working.
Please help me in this regard.

```
#navigation{
height: 200px;
margin: 0;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
width: 200px;
        }
li {
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  float: left;
  height: 198px;
  list-style: none outside none;
  width: 198px;
  position: relative;
}

<div><ul id="navigation">
                <li class="active">List 1</li>
                <li>List 2</li>
                <li>List 3</li>
            </ul></div>



setInterval(function slider(){             

$("#navigation li").addClass("active").animate({                         
                    top : "-=198"
                },function(){
                    $("#navigation li").removeClass("active").next().addClass("active");
                   $("#navigation").append($("#navigation li:first");
                });

                },1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way :

```
setInterval(function slider(){
    var act = $('#navigation li');
    act.animate({
        top: '-198px'
    },function(){
        act.css('top','0').first('li').appendTo('#navigation')
    });
  },4000)
```

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9TpcE/2/)**

Comment: Danko Bravo! God Help you. This is what i was looking for. You solved my problem. Thanx Thanx alot

Answer (score 0):

I've created a jsFiddle.  Can you explain again what you are trying to achieve again?  This fiddle will animate the display of each list item onLoad.  I modified your li css settings display to none.  Then with jQuery I loop through the list items and use the slideDown function to create the animation.  Hopefully this will at least get you closer to what you are looking for.

```
$( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
  $( this ).slideDown( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

[jsFiddle - Animate list items](http://jsfiddle.net/7Uuk3/)

Comment: Thanx for your quick support can you please complete the whole code I have tried but not working.

Comment: Check out Danko's post.  I think it's exactly what you are looking for. Upvote for Danko. Make sure you accept his answer :)